# Single sign on both for Dynamics CRM and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, adal.js

I have integrated ADAL.js library into my Dynamics CRM in a custom solution. When login or token is expired it is asking for login prompting a login window of AD.

I have already logged in to my CRM, so that second login prompt is quite annoying for users.

Can I implement in this scenario single sign-in - or how else to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you use a sliding expiry rather than absolute? (Expire after a time of inactivity rather than a fixed time)

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I have the same exact issue.